# Difference between $\tilde{\textrm{Diff}}_+(S^1)$ and ${\textrm{Diff}}_+(S^1)$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, conformal-field-theory

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0610197), where Liouville theory is being studied on a strip, after equation 2.3 it is mentioned that the conformal transformations of the strip are given by the same chiral and anti-chiral coordinate transformations, $x\to\xi(x),\ \bar x\to\xi(\bar x)$. But the associated group is identified as $\tilde{\textrm{Diff}}_+(S^1)$ which is the cover of ${\textrm{Diff}}_+(S^1)$.

Does the subscript '$+$' denote orientation preserving transformations?

What is the difference between the two groups and what conformal transformations are included in the covering group but not the original group?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/88386. Also see the notation used in theorem 11 on page 12 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08471